# Looking for an Open Source WCF Proxy Generator

Tags: .net

Are there any open source proxy generators for WCF? The one that is built into Visual Studio kinda sucks and I would like one that either works better or can be modified to do so.

For example, I really need OnXxxChanging and OnXxxChanged partial methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you already know [wscf.blue](http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/)

I'm not sure if their datacontract generator does what you need but it comes with source code

Although I never used it I had the impression that you could also extend the WCF metadata pipeline to replace the code generation with something more sophisticated. Here is the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730243.aspx) doc. The [IWsdlImportExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.iwsdlimportextension.aspx) looks interesting.